# Yield in view for multiple blocks

Tags: ruby, layout, sinatra, erb

I am writing a small Sinatra-based app and would like each view to be able to insert various items into the layout, for example the page `title` or extra CSS/javascript references in the `head`.

Currently my layout (erb) looks like this (simplified):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hard Coded Title Here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" ... />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hard Coded Title Here</h1>
    <div id="content">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Rather than having the title and CSS/JS references hard coded, I'd like to achieve something along these lines:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><%= yield :title %></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" ... />
    <%= yield :more_head_refs %>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><%= yield :title %></h1>
    <div id="content">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And be able to define the content for those blocks from within each view.

Is this possible, and if so how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up against this issue at Railscamp recently and luckily Tim Lucas was able to point me to something he forked and worked on called [sinatra-content-for](http://github.com/toolmantim/sinatra-content-for). This will cover what you need.

Comment: Development has since continued under the project [sinatra-content-for2](http://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra-content-for2).

Answer (score 3):

I've found this to be the most robust solution for Rails-style 'content_for' functionality in Sinatra, especially if you're using ERB templates rather than Haml:

http://github.com/kematzy/sinatra-outputbuffer

Answer (score 0):

You can just use @stylesheet in your ruby file